# Small Signal OTA Circuit

Tags: electrical-engineering

[image]
I am having some difficulty determining the constants $a, b, k$ in the open circuit voltage transfer function $T(s) = v_{0}/v_{i}(s)$, which is given by $T(s) = \dfrac{k [s + a]}{[s + b]}$

I know that the constants must be in terms of the elements $\{C_{1}, C_{2}, gm1, gm2, GL[=1/RL]\}$ positive. I also know that the $gm$ can be negative when switching the input terminal.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the first OTA meant to be hanging in the breeze with only two connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The op amp in the left of the circuit don't do anything;
The op amp in the right is connected like a comparator, with positive feedback. That means it's output will be VCC or GND depending on Vi, not intermediate values.